# Instagram In-App Browser Covers Site Header and Bottom CTA

Tags: instagram, inappbrowser

My site has a bottom CTA that slides up after a user selects their colors before purchasing. However, Instagram's In-App browser nav covers the CTA and the site header instead of starting them above (and below), respectively. No other social media In-App browser does this (including Facebook and Facebook Messenger!).

Is there any solve, other than sniffing out IG browser and customizing the CTA height for this only scenario? (Not ideal)

ATTACHED LINKS: Image 1 How it appears on IG / Image 2: How it appears on Facebook (and all other in-app browsers)

Thank you!!!

[IMAGE 1: Instagram In-App Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx0En.png)
/ [IMAGE 2: Facebook Functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6X3BX.png)

Comment: I am having the same issued with a fixed footer with Insta in-app browser.